# Format of output tiles from tippecanoe?

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles

I generated a mbtiles file with [tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe) and extracted it with [mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) to filesystem. (It named them all .png)

Anyhow, what format are these tiles in? I tried parsing them with a vector tile parser but it gave me an exception using the C# mapbox-vector-tile project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Build vector tilesets from large collections of GeoJSON features.

They are [Mapbox Vector Tiles](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/vector-tiles/).

Comment: THanks. just needed the confirmation. I will assume it is the https://github.com/bertt/mapbox-vector-tile-cs project that has some issues for now. Need to verify this also.

Comment: I found out what my issue was and it was related to content being gzipped and I was not handling this.